# Can't add .icls theme file to IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ ultimate edition, and I'm on a mac. I'm trying to install [this](https://draculatheme.com/jetbrains/) theme. My folder structure looks as follows:

~Library/Preferences/IntelliJ/colors/Dracula.icls

the IntelliJ folder wasn't there so I created that myself. I also tried IntelliJVersionNumber and that also didn't work. IntelliJ doesn't seem to be recognizing this theme. When I go to change the theme in preferences it only shows the default ones (which ironically one of the default ones is also called Dracula)

Comment: You must use the [existing folder](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519).

Comment: There is no existing folder though. That's why I had to add them

Comment: There is one, you are looking in the wrong location.

Comment: I'm looking at ~Library/Preferences  just like it says. Is there any other place I should be looking?

Comment: `~/Library/Preferences` is not the same as `/Library/Preferences`. `~` stands for your user home folder, so it's actually `/Users/<username>/Library/Preferences`.

Comment: oh wow thanks. I just got the mac from my new job and I had no clue. make a new answer and I'll accept it if you want the rep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~/Library/Preferences` is not the same as `/Library/Preferences`. `~` stands for your user home folder, so it's actually `/Users/<username>/Library/Preferences`.

[See the FAQ](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519).